# Graphing mean and standard deviation

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, statistics

I have measurements for multiple devices, and have their mean and sd values. I would like to produce a chart that would show these values, and I think the best would be if I could have something that looks like a bar chart(-ish) - the device names in x axis, values in y axis, and for each device to have a 'floating' bar that would represent values (mean - sd :: mean + sd), and some marker in the middle to show the actual mean value. is it doable? or would you suggest some other chart?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [box-and-whisker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) plot.

Here are instructions to create them in Excel:

- *edit:* [Box plot and whisker plots in Excel 2007](http://blog.immeria.net/2007/01/box-plot-and-whisker-plots-in-excel.html) (most detailed steps and best looking output)
- [Boxplots in Excel](http://www.coventry.ac.uk/ec/~nhunt/boxplot.htm)
- [How to create a BoxPlot/Box and Whisker Chart in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155130)
- There are probably 3rd party tools to help, too.

Usually the median, quartile, and extreme values are used; but you could use mean and standard deviation(s).

Comment: thanks a lot for the lead, the top one is a great tutorial. the only problem so far is I can't seem to get the mean values on to the graph - the instructions only work for a single data series. the problem seems to be that XY plot can't take strings (device names) as values - at least, when I try to put it that way, it recognizes the Y series as 0, 0, 0... . Would you have any ideas? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you just have two or three devices and their data, you could use a **Normal distribution** or **Bell curve** to plot your mean and standard deviation. But if you have more devices, I recommend you to use **Box Plot**. I made a sample for your problem and it looks like this.

[image]

**HighLights**

While Excel doesn't have original box plot support, you could draw this kind of chart easily using JavaScript libaries like HightCharts.js that I'm using for this sample. You could use Funfun to write and run JavaScript code in Excel, so that drawing a box plot like this would be easier in Excel. Here is the code that I used in the Funfun Online Editor:

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a364ae474efa7334ff27269

The box plot could give the readers more information about your measurements. But you need to make some modification to your data. In this case, I used **quartile** and **median** to reveal the data. So in order to draw this chart, your data should look like this.

```
           Minimum  Maximum Lower quartile  Higher Quartile Median
 Device1     760      801        848             895         965
 Device2     733      853        939             980         1080
 Device3     714      762        817             870         918
```

Then, with the code in the link above, you could use FunFun add-in to load the chart directly into your excel using the URL above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is this one: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/

- Supports vertical and horizontal charts
- Displays the mean in addition to the quartiles and median.
- Comes with an Excel file to tweak for quick results.