# Boxplots in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Excel does not come with [boxplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) charts.

What is the best technique to simulate [boxplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) charts in Excel?

I'm interested to

- draw horizontal and vertical charts
- display the mean in addition to the quartiles and median.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/132038/excel-graphing-mean-and-standard-deviation

Answer (score 3):

The best I've found is this one: [**Peltier Tech Box and Whisker Chart Utility for Excel**](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/)

[image]

- Supports vertical and horizontal charts
- Displays the mean in addition to the quartiles and median.
- Comes with an Excel file to tweak for quick results.

Comment: You might need to install the service pack for Excel 2008 Mac to have "custom error bars", as requested per the technique. Service pack I had to install: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=7799